# Turning Off/Disabling AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having cross domain issues with an AngularJS and IE8, and IE9. And I've tried

```
MyApp.config(['$httpProvider',
function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

Luckily the whole site was built with a NoJS fallback in place. My question is how can I turn off AngularJS for only IE8 and IE9 so the fallback is used but keep it on for all other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
[if gt IE 8]    
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<![endif]>
```

Comment: You actually won't get any errors, but your HTML will have Angular bits speckled everywhere.  Either way he said he designed the site with a NoJS fallback, although I'm not entirely sure what that means.

Comment: NoJS Fallback means for whatever reason javascript is not working, the site is mostly still usable, just no flashy provided by js.

Comment: I was initially compiling angularjs with the app into one file. With your solution, I would have seperate the library and app into two separate files.